# Answering to ussd menu programmatically

Tags: android, ussd

I have searched a lot to find a solution to answer to ussd menu but didn't find any. I found a way to get a response text but now I'm in need to reply to ussd menu.
Is there a way to do such a thing programmatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Me too stuck bro

Comment: have you got any solution?